# Pandas Read_csv() lambda layer issue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am currently trying to create a lambda layer so that I can import csv files as pandas dataframes within a lambda function. I tried using the AWS-managed layer (AWSDataWrangler layer) but this does not work either.

I've created 'python' file containing:

[image]

I then zip this file and upload it as a lambda layer. I get this error when I try to pd.read_csv() from my s3 bucket:

```
  "errorMessage": "Install s3fs to access S3",
  "errorType": "ImportError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/ManifestValidationLambda/manifest_validation.py\", line 19, in handler\n    df = pd.read_csv('s3://' + s3_bucket_name +'/' + s3_key, header = 0)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pandas/util/_decorators.py\", line 311, in wrapper\n    return func(*args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py\", line 586, in read_csv\n    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py\", line 482, in _read\n    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py\", line 811, in __init__\n    self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py\", line 1040, in _make_engine\n    return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pandas/io/parsers/c_parser_wrapper.py\", line 51, in __init__\n    self._open_handles(src, kwds)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pandas/io/parsers/base_parser.py\", line 222, in _open_handles\n    self.handles = get_handle(\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pandas/io/common.py\", line 609, in get_handle\n    ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pandas/io/common.py\", line 358, in _get_filepath_or_buffer\n    file_obj = fsspec.open(\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/fsspec/core.py\", line 452, in open\n    return open_files(\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/fsspec/core.py\", line 286, in open_files\n    fs, fs_token, paths = get_fs_token_paths(\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/fsspec/core.py\", line 622, in get_fs_token_paths\n    cls = get_filesystem_class(protocol)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/fsspec/registry.py\", line 221, in get_filesystem_class\n    raise ImportError(bit[\"err\"]) from e\n"
  ]
}
```

Here is my python code:

```
s3_bucket_name = 'bucketname'
    s3_key = 'csv file name'

    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

    # obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=s3_bucket_name, Key=s3_key)
    # #print(obj['Body'])

    df = pd.read_csv('s3://' + s3_bucket_name +'/' + s3_key, header = 0)
    print(df.head(2))
```

You can see that I have the s3fs package within the zip directory. How should I resolve this?

Comment: I've done this with the AWS Data Wrangler layer without issues. I don't think you can read directly from S3 like you are trying without the Data Wrangler library. I suggest switching back to the Data Wrangler layer so you at least know the layer is built correctly, and then posting your Data Wrangler code and errors if you still run into a problem.

Comment: Note it would be wranger.s3.read_csv() with the Data Wrangler layer available. You don't call pandas.read_csv() directly.

Comment: @MarkB got it. what about the dataframe transformation methods from pandas? do those exist in the wranger layer?

Comment: Yes, the wrangler layer includes pandas and all the pandas dependencies.

Comment: @MarkB thanks, this solves my issue. I'd be curious to figure out why my custom layer doesn't work, but I'll look at it later.